# Kafka Connect cannot cast custom storage sink partitioner to Partitioner interface

Tags: java, kotlin, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I need to create a custom partitioner for the kafka connect [S3 sink plugin](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/kafka-connect-s3/index.html).
I've extended the [HourlyPartitioner](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-storage-common/blob/5.3.2-post/partitioner/src/main/java/io/confluent/connect/storage/partitioner/HourlyPartitioner.java) in a custom class using kotlin:

```
class RawDumpHourlyPartitioner<T> : HourlyPartitioner<T>() {
...
}
```

and changed my connector config accordingly to use the custom class:

```
"partitioner.class": "co.myapp.RawDumpHourlyPartitioner",
```

I've then created our jar (we use [shadow](https://imperceptiblethoughts.com/shadow/)) and included it into a custom docker image based on the kafka connect image (the image version is the same as the dependencies we use in the project):

```
FROM gradle:6.0-jdk8 as builder
WORKDIR /app
ADD . .
RUN gradle clean shadowJar

FROM confluentinc/cp-kafka-connect:5.3.2

COPY --from=builder /app/build/libs/kafka-processor-0.1-all.jar /usr/share/java/kafka/kafka-processor.jar
```

When the connector starts I get this error:

```
ERROR WorkerSinkTask{id=staging-raw-dump-0} Task threw an uncaught and unrecoverable exception (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask)
java.lang.ClassCastException: co.myapp.RawDumpHourlyPartitioner cannot be cast to io.confluent.connect.storage.partitioner.Partitioner
```

To double check I've created a java file that tries to instantiate the class and it didn't throw any error:

```
import io.confluent.connect.storage.partitioner.Partitioner;

public class InstantiateTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException {
        Class<? extends Partitioner<?>> partitionerClass =
                (Class<? extends Partitioner<?>>) Class.forName("co.myapp.RawDumpHourlyPartitioner");

        Partitioner<?> partitioner = partitionerClass.newInstance();
    }
}
```

Comment: What does your class do that's not available in hourly or time-based partitioner? Try putting the JAR in `/usr/share/java/kafka-connect-storage-common`. Also, what is your `CONNECT_PLUGIN_PATH` set at?

Comment: @cricket_007 partition based on custom avro fields + time, `CONNECT_PLUGIN_PATH=/usr/share/java/,/usr/share/confluent-hub-components/`
Class is loaded correctly, if I set another non existing class name I get a null pointer exception

Comment: If I add my jar to `/usr/share/java/kafka-connect-storage-common` I get another error, because we use the same jar to provide a custom `CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER_VALUE_SUBJECT_NAME_STRATEGY` and with the jar in that directory it's not able to find the custom strategy class

Comment: Your JAR has nothing to do with the subject strategy. Did you shadow your class wrong? You need to mark the kafka dependencies as provided in the Gradle, by the way

Comment: BTW, sounds like you rewrote this https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-storage-common/pull/73

Comment: @cricket_007 yeah it's similar, just less generalized. Btw my JAR also includes a custom subject strategy set in the main connect config (not specific to a single connector) so I need both classes (partitioner and subject strategy) to be available to kafka-connect and in the connectors

Comment: @cricket_007 oh sorry let me check how to mark the dependencies as provided, right now I've only tried to exclude them from the jar but that didn't work

Comment: So since I use `build.gradle.kts` I've set the dependency as compileOnly but I get `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/confluent/connect/storage/partitioner/HourlyPartitioner` (probably because I've moved the jar back to `/usr/share/java/kafka` to get the strategy working), maybe I should create 2 jars, one with the partitioner in the storage common folder and the other one in the main folder with the custom strategy?

Comment: @cricket_007 I've probably found the issue, since the connector is the s3 sink connector, I have to put it in the `/usr/share/java/kafka-connect-s3` directory, this works fine with the compileOnly dependency of kafka-connect-storage-partitioner

Comment: Yes, I would suggest using separate modules/jars for the partitioner and the strategy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the kafka connect [guide](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/userguide.html#installing-plugins) it says:

> A Kafka Connect plugin is simply a set of JAR files where Kafka Connect can find an implementation of one or more connectors, transforms, and/or converters. Kafka Connect isolates each plugin from one another so that libraries in one plugin are not affected by the libraries in any other plugins. This is very important when mixing and matching connectors from multiple providers.

This means that since I'm using the S3 sink connector, I have to put my jar with the custom partitioner in the directory of the S3 plugin.

Moving the jar file to `/usr/share/java/kafka-connect-s3` solved the issue

In the comments I've mentioned that my jar also includes a custom subject name strategy that we use in the main kafka-connect config (the env variables), in that case the jar needs to be in the `/usr/share/java/kafka` folder

**Update**: as [cricket_007](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2308683/cricket-007) mentioned it's better to put the custom partitioner jar into the `/usr/share/java/kafka-connect-storage-common` folder which is where all the other partitioners are

Comment: That's not true. I'm currently running S3 sink with custom partitioners in the folder I mentioned above. Plus, that's where the hourly partitioner exists anyway. Your schema registry class needs to be on the CLASSPATH, and it should go in the schema registry directory, not Kafka

Comment: I'll do some more tests in a few days and update the answer accordingly, in the meantime I was able to create a jar just with the partitioner class and that worked well

Comment: @cricket_007 that works, so what's the benefit of using the storage vs the s3 folder? Just a better place to be in the storage folder since it's where the other partitioners are?

Comment: @cricket_007 do you want to add your own response so I can mark yours as the accepted one or do I just update mine?

Comment: Yours is fine. I was just adding commentary

Answer (score 0):

Depending on which Sink you use, We need to push partitioner class there, as in our case when we were using Confluent Kafka 5.5 , and connector class Azure Gen2 Storage.

For that we need to write custom partitioner similar to following [Repo in Github](https://github.com/canelmas/kafka-connect-field-and-time-partitioner).

Then We place the custom JAR in following path:

```
/usr/share/confluent-hub-components/confluentinc-kafka-connect-azure-data-lake-gen2-storage/lib/
```

After which our connector class working successfully!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  I suggest you improve your answer, have a look here → [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Also, while this link of the GitHub Repo may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.